# Download permission for non-purchased products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I implemented a webshop for downloadable products using WooCommerce 2.6. The webshop sells individual products (two license types / variations) and bundles of these individual products. A bundle is the same as an individual product, but holds references to other products using a custom field. The download links are stored within the individual products. The bundles do not hold any download links.

I would like to display the download links of the individual products bought in a bundle. Unfortunately i run into the following problem: WooCommerce does not know that a user has the permission to download individual products contained in a bought bundled.

Is there a way to generate download permissions without having the products in an order? If no, can I add the products to an order during/after checkout without raising the subtotal? Are there any other workarounds I could fix this issue?